# Compile resx files in the project or just use resgen without compiling resx

Tags: c#, localization, compilation, resx, resgen

I am using 2 resx files in my project one for en-Us and other for de-DE (localization).

I compile these resx files to resource files using resgen.

Can anyone please help me on the following two questions:

1. If I need to add more resx files in the project say for fr-FR, would I need to compile the project again after adding he new resx file for fr-Fr in the project or can I just create the resx file and generate the .resources file from the resx using resgen tool without compiling the Visula studio project?
2. Can the .resource file generated from resx using resgen be embedded in the exe or would it remain as a standalone compiled binary alongwith the exe that uses the resources file?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK

1 - You can re-create new .resource file and just replace the old one

2 - You have to deploy resource files along with your assemblies

see more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht.aspx